registering for COM fails because referenced assembly is not registered
I have an assembly containing the following classes that should be exposed to COM:
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel;    

namespace Interop
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
    public interface ITestCase 
    {
        TestCase TestCase { get; }  // this is where ObjectModel from VS comes into play
    }

    [ComVisible(true)]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [ComDefaultInterface(typeof(ITestCase))]
    public class TestCaseWrapper : ITestCase
    {
        public TestCase TestCase { get; }
    }
}

So you see I have a wrapper-assembly around Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.TestCase in order to make it COM-visible. My project has the Register for COM-interop-option enabled. However when compiling, it complains with the following error:

The assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel,
Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' is
not registered for COM Interop. Please register it with regasm.exe
/tlb. Interop

I'm using .net framework 4.7.1.
What can I do here?

Can you map TestCase onto your own Model class mark it as ComVisible and surface that one here? I assume everything surfaced via COM must be COM visible (excluding basic types). Maybe its sufficient to not map but to just wrap TestCase with your own class.

@Ralf yeap, that was my thought as well. Trying to serialize the TestCase to my own com-visible type.

If you have references to other types in your class, you need to make these types COM-visible as well. However that's often not possible, because these types are not under your control. However you can create your own representation for these types, as you usually don't need literally that specific type in your COM-library, but just a few information, e.g. just the TestCases name:
namespace Interop
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
    public interface ITestCase 
    {
        string TestCase { get; } 
    }

    [ComVisible(true)]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [ComDefaultInterface(typeof(ITestCase))]
    public class TestCaseWrapper : ITestCase
    {
        public string TestCase { get; }
    }
}


You can use powershell and execute command
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe "your path to dll" /codebase

